# Does synchronizing on the static field that you are modifying make your code thread safe?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

```
class A {
  private static BigInteger staticCode = BigInteger.ZERO;
  private BigInteger code;
  public A() {
    synchronized(staticCode) {
      staticCode = staticCode.plus(BigInteger.ONE);
      code = staticCode;
    }
  }

 }
```

I'm not an expert in concurrency by any means. Could someone explain to me why the class provided above isn't thread safe?

What are the situations that can cause a race condition? My thought process is that if we create 10 instances of this class, every instance will synchronize on a different value of `staticCode` and that's why it's thread safe, but I was told that it wasn't. But why?

I know that we can synchronize on `.class` and it will definitely be thread safe, but I still want to understand this particular situation.

Comment: The title asks does it make the code *thread-safe*, the body asks if the code isn't *thread-safe*.

Comment: The only current answer highlights the problem. It starts "No", but to which question?

Comment: Ask the poster. Why are you asking me? My main question is at the top.

Comment: @hey_you who is "the poster", if not you?

Comment: The poster of the answer I mean. It is quite clear from the context which question he answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does synchronizing on the static field that you are modifying make your code thread safe?

No, because you're reassigning it. (*)

As soon as that reassignment has taken place, you've effectively lost the mutual exclusion on access to the `staticCode` field.

- Any thread which is already waiting at the `synchronized` block before the assignment will continue to wait.
- Any thread which arrives at the `synchronized` block after the reassignment but before the reassigning thread has left the block will attempt to synchronize on the *new* value of `staticCode`.

  A more subtle point than the fact you don't have mutual exclusion is that you also lose the happens-before between the end of the synchronized block and the start of the next execution. This means that you don't have guaranteed visibility of the updated value, so you can potentially generate multiple instances of `A` with the same `code`.

It's a bad idea to synchronize on a non-final member. If you don't want to synchronize on `A.class`, you can define an auxilliary member on which to synchronized:

```
class A {
  private static final Object lock = new Object();
  private static BigInteger staticCode = BigInteger.ZERO;

  public A() {
    synchronized (lock) {
      staticCode = ...
    }
  }
}
```

This preserves the mutability of `staticCode`, but allows correct mutual exclusion.

However, an `Atomic*` class would be far easier because you avoid the need to synchronize (e.g. `AtomicInteger` or `AtomicLong` - but if you really think you're going to have more than 2^63 things, you can use an `AtomicReference<BigInteger>`):

```
class A {
  private static final Object lock = new Object();
  private static AtomicReference<BigInteger> staticCode = new AtomicReference<>(BigInteger.ZERO);

  public A() {
    BigInteger code;
    do {
      code = staticCode.get();
    } while (!staticCode.compareAndSet(code, code.add(BigInteger.ONE)));
    this.code = code;

    // Even easier with AtomicInteger/Long:
    // this.code = BigInteger.valueOf(staticCode.incrementAndGet());
  }
}
```

---

(*) But anyway, dispense with the notion that synchronizing automatically makes something thread safe. For one thing, you need to define precisely what you mean by "thread safe"; but then, you need to understand what synchronization actually provides for you, in order to evaluate whether those things satisfy your thread safety requirements.

Comment: What if I had just the first line within synchronized that modified only staticCode, but didn't assign to code? Would it be thread safe then?

Comment: `AtomicReference` would be easier in this case. But mutable statics, even like this, aren't a great idea.

Comment: Also worth noting that to ensure visibility of the change (in the case you're not using the `Atomic*` classes), any *reads* of the variable also need to be synchronized on the same lock as the writes.

Comment: This answer somewhat obscures the fact, which the OP [already has discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60423517/801894), that you _can't_ "synchronize on a static field." You can't synchronize on _any_ field or any variable. You can only synchronize on the _object_ to which some field or variable refers.

Comment: I was thinking the since 1.8 methods rather than `compareAndSet` loops. Those are the easier ones. `this.code = staticCode.getAndUpdate(v -> v.add(BigInteger.ONE));` or `this.code = staticCode.getAndAccumulate(BigInteger.ONE, BigInteger::add);` (`updateAndGet` and `accumulateAndGet` also available). As a nit, the `AtomicReference` `staticCode` should be `final`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the main point I was missing here is that we synchronize on objects, not references to objects.

Consider a situation where I synchronize on BigInteger.ZERO, and then enter the synchronized block.

When the value of staticCode has changed and become BigInteger.ONE, this block still continues to be synchronized on BigInteger.ZERO. Meanwhile another thread is already synchronized on BigInteger.ONE, before we even had a change to assign BigInteger.ONE to code. That second thread could bump staticCode to the value of 2, and now both threads are before the second assignment, but the value of staticCode is 2, so they can both assign the same value of staticCode to 2 different instances of the class.